# Python Multiply Matrix by Vector of Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Does anybody know of a way (preferably using numpy or something similar) to multiply a matrix by a vector of matrices and obtain the desired product shown below? Basically the idea is to follow the normal rules of matrix multplication of a matrix and a vector, only the elements of the vector are matrices themselves and not numbers.[image]

Comment: The inputs are (3,3), and (3,3,3).  What's the shape of the result?

Comment: Is that second matrix suppose to be a vector of identical repeating matricies for each of the vector element (as shown in your diagram)? If that is the case, then wouldn't it be more efficient to represent the first matrix as a 9 element vector? The answer then would be just (a,b,c,....) dot (1,1,1,...) then multiplied with the greek letter matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you can try this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3, 3, 3)
b = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
print(f"A=\n{A}\n\nb=\n{b}")
```

It gives:

```
A=
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]

b=
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Then:

```
out = (b@A.transpose(2, 0, 1)).transpose(1, 2, 0)
print(out)
```

which gives:

```
[[[ 45  48  51]
  [ 54  57  60]
  [ 63  66  69]]

 [[126 138 150]
  [162 174 186]
  [198 210 222]]

 [[207 228 249]
  [270 291 312]
  [333 354 375]]]
```

The matrix `out[0]` is equal to `0*A[0] + 1*A[1] + 2*A[2]`, `out[1]` is equal to `3*A[0] + 4*A[1] + 5*A[2]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to calculate:

```
# Define two matrices
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
B = np.arange(9, 18).reshape(3, 3)

# First calculate the desired result:
rows = []
for i in range(3):
    rows.append([A[i, j] * B for j in range(3)])
result = np.stack(rows).sum(axis=1)
assert(result.shape == (3, 3, 3))
print(result)

[[[ 27  30  33]
  [ 36  39  42]
  [ 45  48  51]]

 [[108 120 132]
  [144 156 168]
  [180 192 204]]

 [[189 210 231]
  [252 273 294]
  [315 336 357]]]
```

Is this correct?

If so, then here is the same calculation using numpy's [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) function:

```
C = np.array([B] * 3)  # shape (3, 3, 3)
result = np.einsum("ij,jkl->ikl", A, C)
```